# set permissions on a file created by javascript

Tags: javascript, sdk, permissions

First of all I'm new here so please don't be too harsh on me :)

I'm developing an add-on for firefox with SDK. It involves clicking on a button which exports a string to a file. This works fine when the file already exists *but* when it is created (indirectly) by the click, its rights are set to `000` (or `---------`). If I manually change the permissions with `chmod`, then the exportation of the string works fine.

**Question**: Is there a way to make the add-on create a *readable* file? (e.g. `660`)

I guess this could be dangerous since you could create executable files on any computer... but there must be a way?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. It's much more basic than I thought; I answer and let the moderators delete the question if need be.

The easiest way to set the permissions is when the file is created. In my case, the `0666` option does it:

```
var outputStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
                   .createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
outputStream.init(file, 0x04 | 0x08 | 0x10, 0666, 0);
```